# How to write a custom angular filter in JavaScript? Slice is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slice

I am trying to write a classic filter that reduces the resulting array - using `slice()` doesn't work as it seems that it actually removes the data. How do I write a custom filter without messing with the actual data so that when the filter is removed the result updates?

Alternatively - the reason I need the custom filter is to perform a filter on more than one field. I know you can filter the whole thing, or you can filter one using `{fieldName:filterVar}` but how do I do that with multiple wihtout making a long list of fieldnames in the DOM (meaning how do I do it in a `.filter()`?)

I am trying to do this in a $filter function without having to string these together like this.

`<tr ng-repeat="(id, item) in items | filter:{firstName:variablez} | filter:{lastName:variablez}"></tr>`

I am leaving the variable the same to show that I'm using the same value to filter multiple fields.

```
    .filter('filterFreetext', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (items, searchFilter) {

var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName'];

               // return 
          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
     if (items[i][fields[j]].indexOf(searchFilter)) {
         items.splice(i, 1);
     }
 }
```

}
}]);

Comment: could you create plunkr/fiddle of your issue

Comment: I updated my question. Hopefully that helps

Comment: We can't see where your problems lie if you don't share what you have tried in your custom filter. `slice()` is destructive, but you can run any conditions you need inside `Array.prototype.filter` and return the resultant array without affecting original

Comment: updated again with some more of my code.

Comment: FYI: `splice` changes the array. `slice` doesn't